# How to optimist an outcome that is the product of several variables

Tags: python, max, regression

I have a Data frame that has 7 Cols. One of which is a col that I want to maximize (make it a target/output, Im not sure). The other cols are factors that could impact that outcome. How do I run the other columns to maximize my function. 
EG, in the tips DF how do I find the right combination that maximizes the tips given. Some of the variable are objects (male/female). 
I've tried regression but it doesn't work.
I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even possible?
Thank you